# Eclipse CDT can't add .h files to path automatically

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I use Eclipse CDT develop a C project in Windows.When i build the project, it throws some errors said the c file invoke .h files these file can't find. But actually, these files are available, it looks like the Eclipse CDT can't add them path? why not CDT add them to path automatically, like java? The make file is generated by Eclipse, i'm just begin to use Eclipse CDT, who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to add the paths as follows (covering a little bit more than what was asked) :

See [gcc man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) :

`-L` : Add a directory to the list of directories to be searched for `-l`

`-l` : The name of the library to be searched (without `lib*` prefix and extension)

For example: `libmylib.a` would be linked using linker option `-lmylib`

and :

`-I` : Add a directory to the list of directories to be searched for `header` files.

Each of those options can be repeated several times when passed to the compiler.

***In CDT :***

- To configure includes : "Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC Compiler > Includes"
- To configure libraries : "Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > GCC Linker > Libraries"

Those configurations are also available in "Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > Includes/Libraries". Same rules as above.